# JDBC Connections to Progress OpenEdge from Bonitasoft

Tags: jdbc, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to get a Bonitasoft 5.10.1 server to connect to a Progress OpenEdge server.

As there isn't a `Progress OpenEdge` specific driver listed in the BS client, I'm using the 'generic' JDBC driver instead.

I've now got to the stage testing the connector where I am receiving:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Protocol error.  Session setup failed`

I am curious if:
a) anyone has tried this configuration with Bonitasoft
b) anyone knows what this error means

Comment: Are you selecting a PostgreSQL connector manually yourself? Progress OpenEdge has got nothing to do with PostgreSQL at all! Check http://www.progress.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you, perhaps, need to install the Progress OpenEdge DB ODBC drivers?

Progress <> Postgres, for most purposes you are better off searching for "OpenEdge".

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P190681 lists some possible approaches depending on your version of OpenEdge and the licenses available to you.